# How to match a verb in any tense in Compromise.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nlp, text-processing, nlp-compromise

The rather excellent [compromise.js](https://github.com/spencermountain/compromise) offers, among other things, a `match` function.

I'm struggling to get it to work on variants of a verb:

```
var nlp = require('compromise');
var sentences = [
    'I am discharging you',
    'I have discharged you',
    'I will discharge him',
    'I discharged you',
    'Monkey'
];

let doc = nlp(sentences.join('. '));
console.log(doc.match('discharge').sentences().out('text'));

/* Output:
discharge
*/
```

Above only matches 1 sentence out of an expected 4.
How can I get it to match all 4 sentences shown above that contain a conjugate of the word 'discharge'?

Running the following does correctly find the conjugations of the verb 'discharge':

```
doc.verbs().conjugate()

/* Output:
[ { PastTense: 'discharged',
    PresentTense: 'discharges',
    Infinitive: 'discharge',
    Gerund: 'discharging',
    Actor: 'discharger',
    FutureTense: 'will discharge' },
  { PastTense: 'had',
    PresentTense: 'has',
    Infinitive: 'have',
    Gerund: 'having',
    Actor: 'haver',
    Participle: 'had',
    FutureTense: 'will have' },
  { PastTense: 'discharged',
    PresentTense: 'discharges',
    Infinitive: 'discharge',
    Gerund: 'discharging',
    Actor: 'discharger',
    FutureTense: 'will discharge' },
  { PastTense: 'discharged',
    PresentTense: 'discharges',
    Infinitive: 'discharge',
    Gerund: 'discharging',
    Actor: 'discharger',
    FutureTense: 'will discharge' } ]
  */
```

Answer (score 2):

> The goal of .match() is to provide a quick way to describe any
>   grammatical pattern, or match condition, using a human-readable, and
>   mostly-reasonable style. [Ref](https://observablehq.com/@spencermountain/compromise-match-syntax)

You can use `regex` pattern in `match` and you don't need `sentences`

```js
var nlp = nlp
var sentences = ['I am discharging you','I have discharged you','I will discharge him','I discharged you','Monkey'];

let doc = nlp(sentences.join('. '));

console.log(doc.match('/discharg(ing|e|ed)/').out('text'));

// to capture all verbs

console.log(doc.match('#verb').out('array'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/compromise@latest/builds/compromise.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah, I did see the RegEx option, but thought there might be a build in function for this. I've been looking at the Plugins for compromise.js and wondered if I could use that extensibility for  a more 'polished' solution (especially as this is just one example out of many I am trying to analyse). Do you also know how I can (a) output the full sentence that had the match, rather than just the match iteself? (b) have a bundle of of match patterns and output all sentence(s) that match any 1 pattern in the bundle?

Comment: @Adam i am not very much familiar with this library i need to go through docs, but for capturing complete sentence you can try regex like `/.*discharg(ing|e|ed).*/`

Answer (score 2):

early versions of compromise tried to store a 'root' conjugation for every verb, for this purpose, but It became too slow on a large text.

perhaps the best way to do this is to conjugate the terms in the document to a known tense, then look for it.

```
let doc = nlp('i discharged and was discharging')
doc.verbs().toInfinitive()
doc.match('discharge').length
// 2
```

https://runkit.com/spencermountain/5d080c35d95eb800198fcc78

cheers

Comment: Thanks Spencer. I will try that, but it also seems like it could be slow to do in my use case as I have millions of 1-2 page documents and I’m only pattern matching phrases containing conjugations of 1 of 5 main verbs of interest. Personally I think the tool would be best if it were configurable. Rather than worry about whether the user has a small or large text to contend with and whether they are on client or server-side, have it configurable (default: off) and some comments/docs around the impact of enabling it.